# How can I install aircrack-ng in M1 Macbook?

Tags: macos, command-line, aircrack-ng

Recently I have started taking Ethical Hacking course. Because of some issue with parallels, instead of using Kali Linux, I decided to work on MacOS itself by installing only the necessary tools suggested in the course. But, I'm having trouble installing aircrack-ng through brew or via the method given [here](https://aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#installing_on_mac_osx).

While trying `brew install aircrack-ng` I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error: aircrack-ng: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source aircrack-ng
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

Upon trying the command `brew install --build-from-source aircrack-ng` mentioned in the above message, getting:

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/dexter/Library/Logs/Homebrew/aircrack-ng/02.make:
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include/aircrack-ng/osdep -I/private/tmp/aircrack-ng-20210825-45669-371zkp/aircrack-ng-1.6 -I/private/tmp/aircrack-ng-20210825-45669-371zkp/aircrack-ng-1.6/include -I/private/tmp/aircrack-ng-20210825-45669-371zkp/aircrack-ng-1.6/include -I/private/tmp/aircrack-ng-20210825-45669-371zkp/aircrack-ng-1.6/lib -I/private/tmp/aircrack-ng-20210825-45669-371zkp/aircrack-ng-1.6/lib -I/private/tmp/aircrack-ng-20210825-45669-371zkp/aircrack-ng-1.6/lib/radiotap -I/private/tmp/aircrack-ng-20210825-45669-371zkp/aircrack-ng-1.6/lib/radiotap -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O3 -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-overflow=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -fvisibility=hidden -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-array-bounds -c lib/osdep/darwin.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o lib/osdep/.libs/libaircrack_osdep_la-darwin.o
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

The alternate way mentioned in aircrack-ng.org also kind of gives the same error.

Is there any workaround to make it work?

**Update**:

I have tried using **Rosetta 2** to run Intel based CommandLine apps as mentioned in this [article](https://cutecoder.org/software/run-command-line-apple-silicon/).

Again, brew install aircrack-ng fails during "make install" step. On using --verbose flag, the following error is being printed:

```
In file included from src/aircrack-ng/linecount.cpp:58:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:674:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:423:
./version:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id
1.6.0
^
In file included from src/aircrack-ng/linecount.cpp:58:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:674:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:562:13: error: unknown type name 'ptrdiff_t'
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:623:56: error: unknown type name 'ptrdiff_t'
template<class _Category, class _Tp, class _Distance = ptrdiff_t,
                                                       ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:989:66: error: unknown type name 'ptrdiff_t'
          class _Traits = char_traits<_CharT>, class _Distance = ptrdiff_t>
                                                                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:989:54: error: template parameter missing a default argument
          class _Traits = char_traits<_CharT>, class _Distance = ptrdiff_t>
                                                     ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:989:27: note: previous default template argument defined here
          class _Traits = char_traits<_CharT>, class _Distance = ptrdiff_t>
                          ^
apple-m1
```

Answer (score 1):

Aircrack-ng latest version is 1.6 and release date is Jan/2020, but master branch have a fix for MAC M1 commited 7 months ago.
Using master branch is possible build aircrack-ng in a mac m1.

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng.git

cd aircrack-ng

autoreconf -vif

env CPPFLAGS="-Wno-deprecated-declarations" ./configure --with-experimental

make

make check

sudo make install
```

Works for me.

https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Complains about openssl/libgcrypt (installed it via brew)
checking for OpenSSL or libgcrypt... configure: error: one of OpenSSL or Gcrypt was not found

Comment: Update: I was able to compile it with --with-gcrypt flag to the configure script. Thanks  Alex!

Comment: I also got 'configure: error: one of OpenSSL or Gcrypt was not found'. Got it configured with 'brew install libgcrypt' and 'env CPPFLAGS="-Wno-deprecated-declarations" ./configure --with-experimental --with-gcrypt'

Answer (score 0):

there's written in the docs that aircrack-ns supports osX, did you install the pre requisites?
in the first snippet, you are trying to install aircrack-ng via brew, don't do that, because its probably not available on brew itself, but yet can be compiled and installed from source.

install these according to the docs:

autoconf

automake

libtool

openssl

shtool

pkg-config

via brew. then use these commands:

```
wget https://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.6.tar.gz
tar -zxvf aircrack-ng-1.6.tar.gz
cd aircrack-ng-1.6
autoreconf -i
./configure --with-experimental
make
make install
ldconfig
```

Comment: Yup, as I have already mentioned in the description, I have tried the method given in their [site](https://aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#installing_on_mac_osx).  It gives the same errors, ```expected unqualified-id``` and ```error: unknown type name 'ptrdiff_t'```.